# Feedback on this torrc-defaults file

Tags: configuration, pluggable-transports, ipv6

The following is my `torrc-defaults` file.  I'm trying to learn this stuff so I don't have to ask this kind of question here, yet I'm still in the dark about much of this.  So I'm asking for feedback in regard to the lines pertaining to SOCKS and FTEproxy. Does this all look okay? What if I do not want IPV6? Can I change that line - and if so, to what?

```
AvoidDiskWrites 1
SocksPort 9150 IPv6Traffic PreferIPv6 KeepAliveIsolateSOCKSAuth
ControlPort 9151
CookieAuthentication 1
ClientTransportPlugin fte exec ./TorBrowser/Tor/PluggableTransports/fteproxy.bin --managed
ClientTransportPlugin obfs2,obfs3,obfs4,scramblesuit exec ./TorBrowser/Tor/PluggableTransports/obfs4proxy
ClientTransportPlugin meek exec ./TorBrowser/Tor/PluggableTransports/meek-client-torbrowser -- ./TorBrowser/Tor/PluggableTransports/meek-client
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the valid config options are detailed in the [Tor config manual](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en).

It'd probably be quicker for you to read that than for us to enumerate each of the options included in your question.

> What if I do not want IPV6? Can I change that line - and if so, to
>   what?

Remove the IPV6 options. They are only set if they are included at all. For reference, here's what the manual has to say about them:

> **IPv6Traffic** Tell exits to allow IPv6 addresses in response to SOCKS
>   requests on this connection, so long as SOCKS5 is in use. (SOCKS4
>   can’t handle IPv6.)
>
> **PreferIPv6** Tells exits that, if a host has both an IPv4 and an IPv6
>   address, we would prefer to connect to it via IPv6. (IPv4 is the
>   default.)

Comment: He has a ControlPort, so ipv6 can be enabled on flight

Answer (score 1):

If you have IPv6 network access - yes, it looks OK. Some additions to these ones are the question of taste.